# Convert Timestamp to string in pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the data:

```
[(Timestamp('2020-12-13 01:00:00'), 'Mers'), (Timestamp('2020-12-13 02:00:00'), 'BMW')]
```

Is it possible to convert the timestamp in the data to a string like so:

```
[('2020-12-13 01:00:00', 'Mers'), ('2020-12-13 02:00:00', 'BMW')]
```

If so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Loop over your dataframe, extract the data, replace it with what you want

Comment: @saddy sorry, I was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use panadas [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html#pandas-timestamp-strftime):

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Timestamp(1513393355.5).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

In your example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([(pd.Timestamp('2020-12-13 01:00:00'), 'Mers'), (pd.Timestamp('2020-12-13 02:00:00'), 'BMW')])

# apply strftime to the first (0th) column values:
data[0] = data[0].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Result (`data`):

```py
                     0     1
0  2020-12-13 01:00:00  Mers
1  2020-12-13 02:00:00   BMW
```

```py
>>> data.to_numpy().tolist()

[['2020-12-13 01:00:00', 'Mers'], ['2020-12-13 02:00:00', 'BMW']]
```